# Как предотвратить остановку сервера после отработки задач(тасков) Grunt?

Tags: grunt

*grunt-cli* установлен локально, запуск задачи(таска), производится вызовом функции из кода приложения:

```
    function htmlSnapshot(prefix,suffix){
    grunt.cli({
      gruntfile: __dirname + "/../Gruntfile.js",
      extra: {
          snapshotPath: 'server/snapshots/'+suffix+'/',
          sitePath: 'http://localhost:1111/'+suffix+'/'+prefix,
          fileNamePrefix: prefix
      }
    });
};
```

Конфигурация Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
 var extra = grunt.option('extra');

 grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    htmlSnapshot: {
        all: {
          options: {
            snapshotPath:extra.snapshotPath,
            sitePath:extra.sitePath,
            fileNamePrefix:extra.fileNamePrefix,
            msWaitForPages: 1000,
            sanitize: function (requestUri) {
                if (/\/$/.test(requestUri)) {
                  return 'index.html';
                } else {
                  return requestUri.replace(/\//g, 'prefix-');
                }
            },
            removeScripts: true,
            removeLinkTags: false,
            removeMetaTags: false,
            replaceStrings:[
                {'this': 'will get replaced by this'},
                {'/old/path/': '/new/path'}
            ],
            bodyAttr: 'data-prerendered',
            urls: [
              '',
              '#!/en-gb/showcase'
            ],
            cookies: [
              {"path": "/", "domain": "localhost", "name": "lang", "value": "en-gb"}
            ],
            pageOptions: {
                viewportSize : {
                    width: 1200,
                    height: 800
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-html-snapshot');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlSnapshot']);
};
```

После отработки таска в командной строке выводится следующее уведомление:

> Done, without errors.
>      20 Dec 16:41:21 - [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Как то не вариант,- каждый раз вбивать '*rs*' для рестарта ;).